# What exactly is Least Square Approximation?

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

I tried really hard to understand what exactly the geometrical interpretation of Least Square Approximation but am not able to. I even followed the link but couldn't get what he mean by column space or null space. If someone can provide information on the topic or can tell me where to find relevant information it will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to add the link ----http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC7l96tW8V8

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Answer (score 0):

A bit off topic, posting about pure mathematics, but a bit of googling yielded this:

http://math.mit.edu/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf

It's by MIT, so it's reputable for sure.